# trying to get a link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm actually trying to create a listener with a click function in javascript to create redirections inside a table.

```js
    
    document.body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      const link = evt.target.closest('td.loader');
      if (!link) return;
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = link.href;
    });
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="loader" data-href="http://www.google.com">
          Google
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Don't understand what is missing...help please!

Comment: Can you describe where things go wrong/add some dbg's? -> _"The closest() method traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns null."_

Comment: What happens? What are you expecting? Did you debug? Any error messages?

Comment: So, I've this error message: "document.body.addListener is not a function"

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of syntax errors in yours, try this:

```js
let tableLink = document.querySelector('td.loader');

tableLink.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      const link = tableLink.getAttribute('data-href');
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = link;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="loader" data-href="http://www.google.com">
      Google
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If there are more than one you can leverage a loop and hit it via an element parameter:

```js
let tableLinks = document.querySelectorAll('td.loader');

tableLinks.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      const link = el.getAttribute('data-href');
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = link;
  });
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="loader" data-href="http://www.google.com">
      Google
    </td>
    <td class="loader" data-href="http://www.facebook.com">
      Facebook
    </td>
    <td class="loader" data-href="http://www.youtube.com">
      Youtube
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, when we want to use javascript, it's definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You did a slight mistake here. Links must be in anchor tag. Then only browsers can identify it as a link. So I changed your HTML as below now it's working fine.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="loader">
            <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/">Google</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, and I'll post a new html a little bit more complicated

Comment: Leave a link here. I will try my best

Answer (score -1):

So, to be clear, I didn't find a 100% good solution with javascript. The best I can do is to put a div inside each cell of the table, set with height and width 100% like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="loader">
     <a href="google.com">
       <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
     </a>
      Google
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, I can use this javascript:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
     const link = evt.target.closest('td.loader a');
     if (!link) return;
     evt.preventDefault();
     
     document.body.innerHTML = '<h3 style="color:red">loading link</h3>';
     const href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
     window.location = href;
    });
```

In facts, it works  because I I can use the html link and also the javascript listener. But it's not perfect, due to the css (impossible to have a full cell clickable if some cells are composed with different numbers of lines).

But it's not bad!

At the end, I've realized that semantic ui (I'm using this css framework for this application) purpose a class .selectable who do all the job for me.

Perfect result and less javascript code so I've choosen this solution.

Just in case someone has the same problem, Bootstrap has the same property.

Comment: I'd recommend you don't mix Jquery and standard JS, use one or the other

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely true. Unfortunately, it was a request from my manager to use it :p